# laravel intervention image not displaying image

Tags: laravel, image-processing

Everything seems to be working as I do not get any error but I get garbage code instead of the image itself.  The code is very simple in the controller:

```
// get image & resize
$img = ImgMgr::make('http://pathToImage.jpg')->resize(200,100);
                                
// send HTTP header and output image data
echo $img->response('jpg', 70);
```

Then I get : HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Length: 2900 Content-Type: image/jpeg Date: Wed, 21 Jul 2021 16:05:21 GMT ����JFIF``��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 70 ��C    #%$""!&+7/&)4)!"0A149;>>>%.DIC;��C  ;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;��dd"��

What am I missing?

Comment: Its probably for the header content, try this `return response()->make($img->encode($img->mime()), 200, array('Content-Type' => $img->mime(),'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=86400, public'));`

Comment: How are you using this response to assign to an `<img>` tag?

Comment: @Abishek Now I am just testing, so I am just sending headers at the end of the controller.  But at the end, I will use that route to the controller inside an img tag.

Comment: @sta Thank you but your suggestion gives the same result.

Comment: Here is the solution I found.  Instead of echo, it should be return.

Comment: @PaulGodard yeah, I used `return` too instead of echo, anyway, you need to send Content-Type, cause on some browser it may not work otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution...

```
$img = ImgMgr::make('http://pathToImage.jpg')->resize(200,100);
$img->response('jpg', 70);
$type = 'png';
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($img);

<img src="{!! $base64 !!}">
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?